# Cauchy's inequality in complex analysis, question of being "best possible"

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been stuck on this problem for a long time :
for the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$ show that A. $f^n(z)=\frac{n!}{(1-z)^{n+1}}$ and B.Use A to show that Cauchy's inequality is "best possible" ....I can do part A easily but cannot figure part B ...I believe it has something to do with maximizing or minimizing the denominator in the Cauchy estimate but I am not sure.....

Comment: Write down what the Cauchy estimate gives you (for $f^{(n)}(0)$).

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response ....your suggestion is the first thing I did try ...but still no result....